Insert DateTime to Postgre with C#
Below is my code:
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-8);   //My local time zone is UTC+8
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.UtcNow;            

            Console.WriteLine($"dt1:{dt1} | dt2:{dt2}");  //dt1:2024-05-10 09:46:10 AM | dt2:2024-05-10 09:46:10 AM

            insertDemo(dt1,dt1);
            insertDemo(dt2,dt2);
        }
        public static void insertDemo(DateTime ts,DateTime tsz)
        {
            string connString = "...";
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO demo VALUES (@ts,@tsz)", conn))
                {                    
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ts", ts);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("tsz", tsz);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


Why would the DateTime.UtcNow be modified after inserting it into Postgre, but DateTime.Now wouldn't?
Which is the best practice to store the UTC timestamp on DB?

This SO question might help you.

If you insert DateTime.UtcNow into a column of type timestamptz, PostgreSQL assumes the DateTime is in the local time zone (if the DateTimeKind is Unspecified) and converts it to UTC. This could lead to an apparent "modification" of the time.

Thanks for your answer, but i tried to insert into both columns with/without time zone as  i show in the second picture. Those insertions are modified.
